How to connect to X11 Server
I launched the X11 server via
export DISPLAY=:1
Xvfb $DISPLAY -ac -screen 0 $RES_AND_DEPTH -retro -dpi $DPI -nolisten tcp -nolisten unix

I can communicate with X11 server via xdotool, for example
xdotool getactivewindow

Then I want to figure out that how does xdotool connect to the X11 server. I used strace, it shows that
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X1"}, 20) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X1"}, [124 => 20]) = 0

When I check the /tmp/.X11-unix/X1, it does not exist. So my question is how this connect completed?

\x00/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 is not a regular file, it is an abstract socket!
